# Xamarin Android - Cannot access certain methods of bound Java library?

Tags: android, xamarin, android-library

I'm trying to use the Android Java library [CompactCalendarView](https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView) in Visual Studio 17 using [this Xamarin binding](https://github.com/giuseppenovielli/Xamarin.Android-CompactCalendarView) installed via Nuget.  For the most part, functions work and I can add CompactCalendarViews using the designer.  However, some methods don't seem to exist.  I'm trying to use the `getFirstDayOfCurrentMonth()` method on a created calendar view but Visual Studio gives a CS1061 error stating

```
'CompactCalendarView' does not contain a definition for 'GetFirstDayOfCurrentMonth' and no accessible extension method 'GetFirstDayOfCurrentMonth' accepting a first argument of type 'CompactCalendarView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

The code in question is the following (modified from [here](https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView/issues/88)):

```
        TextView monthAndYear = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.monthYearDisplay);
        monthAndYear.SetText(dateFormatForMonth.Format(eventCalendarView.GetFirstDayOfCurrentMonth()));
```

where `dateFormatForMonth` is a `Java.Text.SimpleDateFormat` object.

I have `using` statements for all three defined packages (base, .Domain, and .Comparators) but it doesn't fix this.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that is was not tranformed to a read-only property: `FirstDayOfCurrentMonth`

Comment: I'm not sure where I'd check this.  I do call `SetFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.Sunday)` but even then `GetFirstDayOfCurrentMonth()` is just an observer so would being read-only stop it from working?

Comment: I'm assuming it has a `getter` only (as you can not change the first day of a month). Xamarin would convert that method call to a property, so just see if it exists `var firstDay = someCalenderInstance.FirstDayOfCurrentMonth;`

Comment: Ah, that did it.  That's strange but I'll keep that in mind in the future.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As SushiHangover said, Xamarin converts the method call into a property, which I was able to access.