# .jar bindings not created correctly in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, binding

I have a external .jar library that I need to import to my project, I have followed the official [Binding a .JAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar) guide and added the .jar as a "EmbeddedJar".

It seems to work fine and I can use the library, but I have now noticed that some minor classes did not get bindings created correctly and the methods/fields are not accessible. I don't get any errors, the expected fields/methods just don't exist. But I do see them when inspecting the .Class object.

What can I try to make sure all classes gets converted correctly? Or, worst case, is it possible add these manually somehow?

Comment: At bottom of doc you linked, see Recommended Content [Java Bindings Metadata](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/customizing-bindings/java-bindings-metadata). This describes manual changes you can make. Perhaps also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings. That is found from the link you gave, by looking at left-hand Navigation Pane for "Troubleshooting Bindings".

Comment: According to this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54908742/xamarin-android-cannot-access-certain-methods-of-bound-java-library), some method in the class such as get set will be convert as a property by the xamarin. In addition, had you compare the resource code between the java class and c# class?